# Load the class on the way

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I have a problem.
I have a absolute path to my package, for example:

```
c:\java_project\src\com\myclass\mypackage
```

In this package is present 3 classes: MyClass1, MyClass2, MyClass3

I need load all classes to List

I load all .java file to List, but I don't understand how this classes load

```
List<URL> fieldURLs=new ArrayList<URL>();
File pathToClasses = null;
pathToClasses = new File(packageName);
File[] files = pathToClasses.listFiles();
```

Please help me with this problem

Comment: you may load a class to JVM using `Class.forName(classname)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

```
List<Class> classes = new LinkedList<>();

for (File file : new File(pathToClasses).listFiles()) {
    classes.add(Class.forName(file.getName().split("\\.")[0])); // if you don't have packages
}

classes.forEach(System.out::println);
```

In my folder I got the following results:

```
class Class1
class Class2
class Class3
```